# Configuring an "Edit with VIM" context menu in Windows 10 WSL using Registry Editor

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, vim, windows-registry, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to implement an "Edit with VIM" option in the Windows context menu for editing text files. I found a method that 'almost' works by adding a registry key to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\`, with an `Open with VIM` title and a `command` subkey with the following value:

```
` bash.exe -c "wslpath '%1' | xargs vim"
```

The key allows me to launch VIM inside Ubuntu WSL with the selected file, but only if the path to the file does not contain a whitespace. For example, for a file under C:\Program Files..., Vim opens with a document under "C:\Program ", slicing the path at the whitespace.

How do I allow a whitespace-containing file path to be accepted as the %1 variable in a registry key?

Comment: Try to add an escape character (\\) like this `wslpath '%1' | sed 's| |\\ |g' | xargs vim`.

Comment: It worked, Thanks!  Would you mind explaining it to me?  It looks to me like it is using the 'sed' command to find ' '(whitespace) and replace it with '\\', however I am not sure what the '\\' does in this context, or if I am misunderstanding the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an escape character (`\`) like this:

```
wslpath '%1' | sed 's| |\\ |g' | xargs vim
```

What this does is replace all `blank` with `\blank`
(meaning   with `\` ).

This way the blank is escaped and no longer serves as a separator,
but just as a normal character within the string.

Comment: It worked, Thanks! Would you mind explaining it to me? It looks to me like it is using the 'sed' command to find ' '(whitespace) and replace it with '\\', however I am not sure what the '\\' does in this context, or if I am misunderstanding the command.

Comment: What's happening here is double-escape, so the argument is evaluated twice. The first shell evaluates the `wslpath` command, so the two antislashes become one. When the `sed` command is executed, the argument it finds is `\ ` (`\space`) so it takes it to mean one space character that isn't a space delimiter.